# Show that the equation $xax=b$ is solvable for $x$ in $G$ iff $ab$ is the square of some element in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that the equation $xax=b$ is solvable for $x$ in a group $G$ iff $ab$ is the square of some element in G.

I need some pointers. Cannot think of a start!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $a$ in terms of $x$ and $b$. Then compute $ab$.

After you try it, see the spoiler below.

> $xax=b$ iff $ax=x^{-1}b$ iff $a=x^{-1}bx^{-1}$ iff $ab=x^{-1}bx^{-1}b=(x^{-1}b)^2$

Conversely, if $ab=y^2$ then you can find $x$ such that $xax=b$:

> From the previous computation, we try $y=x^{-1}b$, that is, $x=by^{-1}$. Then $xax=by^{-1}aby^{-1}=b^{-1}y^2y^{-1}=b$.

Comment: ok, i got the necessary part. for the sufficient part, should i try putting $ab$ for $x$ ?

Comment: for the second part, i did this : let $ab=y^2$ then $xab=b$ implies that $(ax)^2=y^2$ or $ax=y$ then $x=a^{-1}y=a^{-1}ab=b$ does that look good ?

Comment: Indeed, if $ab=y^2,$ then putting $x=a^{-1}y$ means that $$xax=a^{-1}yaa^{-1}y=a^{-1}y^2=a^{-1}ab=b.$$ Your implications aren't true in general, though. In particular, $(ax)^2=y^2$ need not imply that $ax=y$. Consider a group in which all elements but the identity have order $2$.

Comment: @CameronBuie ok, so what would be a more generalized solution ?

Comment: Your solution works in general. Your reasoning doesn't.

Comment: Rather, we could say that in order to have $xax=b,$ we need $$y^2=ab=axax=(ax)^2,$$ so it suffices that $y=ax,$ *I.e.*: $x=a^{-1}y.$